# Bigger than ">" and smaller than "<" symbols in Windows for ANSI layouts

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

How can I use the ">" and "<" symbols on a Windows 10, with an ANSI physical keyboard, but with a "Spanish" (or any other [ISO key layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Physical,_visual,_and_functional_layouts) for that matter like French ([AZERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)), Portuguese, etc.).

On Linux machines, it just works by using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>. On Windows, I can't make it work.

Constantly having to change between layouts, let's say between ENG and SPA, even using shortcuts like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> is not an option.

I can't believe this is such an impossible task to do natively on Windows. Is there a feasible option?

Using combinations like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0060</kbd>, is not desired (imagine writing an XML file like this) nor possible in scenarios with [tenkeyless](https://mechanicalkeyboards.com/shop/index.php?l=product_list&c=27) (80%) keyboards.

Using a third-party software, like [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1020203/typing-and-characters-with-ansi-keyboard-lacking-the-key-these-characters-ar), is not an option as the software is rightfully not allowed in some enterprises (fear of [keylogging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging)).

Comment: `Alt + 0060` is `<` and `Alt + 0062` is `>`. Does that suit?

Comment: Try the key left of 1 for anything you expect to be on the [missing] key left of Z.

Comment: Does the on-screen keyboard help? It might show where it thinks the < and > keys are.